# Работа в midnight commander (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, mc

Всем привет, поставил себе midnight commander (mc), очень понравилось работать через него с локальными файлами.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли `mc` использовать как полноценный ftp/sftp клиент?

В меню увидел 3 пункта:

- FTP-соединение
- Shell-соединение
- SFTP-соединение

Попробовал подключить по sftp, подключился, вроде все норм, но иногда вылетала какая-то 31 ошибка.. но загрузка директорий также работала медленно..
Попробовал подключить через Shell (не понял в чем отличие от sftp - подскажите пожалуйста?) тоже самое, но не было ошибки (31) при переходе по некоторым директориям, и работало чуть быстрее чем через sftp.

Основные вопрос:

1. Можно ли создать список ftp/sftp подключений, чтобы каждый раз не вводить данные для входа? Т.е. иметь готовый список именованных учетных записей.
2. Почему при переходе по директориям разделы открываются с неприятной задержкой (по сравнению с другими файловыми менеджерами)? Может какой-то функционал нужно отключить (подсчет объема данных 
   и etc..?) ?
3. Правильно понимаю, что я могу при подключения по ftp/sftp изменять файлы   через свои сторонние редакторы? 
   Например через sublime text? будет ли при этом при сохранении файл автоматически сохраняться на удаленном сервере?

---

Только начинаю работать в linux и mc,
буду очень благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

соединение по Shell и SSH на первый взгляд  выглядит одинаково, но технически, они работют на разных протоколах, хоть и в обоих случаях используется SSH. отличия могут проявиться например если у вас настроен безпарольный доступ через публичный ключ. Тогда при SSH соединении, MC у вас пароль не станет запрашивать, а при SFTP пароль все-равно придется ввести.

1. вы можете использовать "быстрые каталоги" по "Ctrl+\" чтобы сохранить реквизиты соединения. Пароли при этом не сохраняются, вы можете добавить его вручную в файле hotlist
2. это скорее всего связано не с MC. Можете попробовать снять или выставить флаг пассивного режима в настройках виртуальных ФС. еще замечу, что sftp в принципе медленее ftp.
3. обычно в качестве стороннего вьювера или редактора ставят что-то консольное,  вроде vim или beye... но технически наверно можно поставить и саблим. Если у вас есть необходимость вносить значительные  правки в файлы на удаленных ФС, то можно порекомендовать использовать ftpfs или sshfs.